Braintree Drop-In UI - How can I use Dynamic Pricing For GooglePay and ApplePay elements
I'm trying to integrate GooglePay and ApplePay using the Braintree Drop-In UI.
The problem I have is that on the subscription forms I'm using, there are multiple plan options which change the price depending on which option is selected.
When I initialize the Drop-In, I have to add the prices for GooglePay and ApplePay, as shown below:
googlePay: {
    googlePayVersion: 2,
    merchantId: 'merchant-id-from-google',
    transactionInfo: {
        currencyCode: 'USD',
        totalPriceStatus: 'ESTIMATED',
        totalPrice: '19.99'
    },
    allowedPaymentMethods: [{
        type: 'CARD',
        parameters: {
            billingAddressRequired: true,
            billingAddressParameters: {
                format: 'FULL'
            }
        }
    }]
},
applePay: {
    displayName: 'My Store',
    paymentRequest: {
        total: {
            label: 'My Store',
            amount: '19.99'
        },
        requiredBillingContactFields: ["postalAddress"]
    }
}

What I need to be able to do is to update those prices dynamically as the various subscription options on the form are selected?

Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question in sentence format. Don't add tags.
